# How to keep a document library up to date if the original documents will be changed?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, synchronisation

**Current Situation:** I have a directory with Word document templates and I want to upload them to my SharePoint site. Many people have to work with these templates, but only a few people are able to change these.

**Problem:** If there will be new templates in the directory or changes where made to existing templates, I want that SharePoint keeps track of that and keeps the documents inside the document library updated.

**Restriction:** I want to solve this problem with SharePoint resources. I don't want, for now, solve this Problem with a PowerShell Script or similar!

**Update:** I have the documents in a network directory and I want to display the content of this directory in a list in SharePoint.

Comment: to my opinion you violate the recommendation of "one doc - one source". Why is it necessary to have the templates on file system? Why not keep them only in SharePoint? The versioning of the library does the rest...

Comment: Hi have tried with Office Web App for sharePoint.

Comment: The documents should not be edited by the users. The Users should only get an impression how the document looks, because the template gets filled by another program, which doesn't work together with SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your documents in file system then instead of uploading files, turn on 'Link to document' content type for that library and add those. Users will need read permission and network access to that filepath.

Comment: I have a network path to the template directory, like so S:\Templates\... SharePoint wants that the URL beginns with http or https. But this doesn't work.

Comment: Nope that is not correct, (or maybe it is with the list) but do this:

Comment: Yes your are correct the Link to document has this limitation but try this: 1. Create Links list. Then use UNC path as file link directive. To get the UNC link go to the file server right click on the folder that contains your templates click on properties, now switch to Sharing there you will have your Network Path if the folder is shared if not it needs to be shared. The path will be like \\ServerName\YourFolder append that with the file name, URI directive and change slashes so it looks like this file://ServerName/YourFolder/YourDoc.docx

Comment: I created a links list, but where can i change the file directive to UNC? I can only choose between Link or Picture and both options doesn't work.